# How to get an attribute throw a table in Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have requests table that belongs to subcategories table which belongs to categories table, so from Request model how can I get an attribute from categories?

```
tables

->requests
id
name
subcategory_id


->subcategories
id
name
category_id


->categories
id
name
color
```

So I need to get color from Request model, I already have the tree models created

```
class Request extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->get();
    }

    public function color()
    {
        $somemagicstuff;
        
        return $color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, there is already a class in Laravel called `Request`, that is used in a number of places. You might run into issues with duplicated/ambiguous class resolution. If possible, consider a different name, or make sure to properly handle via `use` statements and `namespacing`

Comment: Yeah, i'm conscious of that I always use an alias for `Request` class

Comment: Excellent :) As for your question, does the `hasManyThrough()` relationship work for you case? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through for reference. Er wait, I think that might be backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your relationships:

```
# Request.php

class Request extends Model
{  
    public function subcategory()
    {    
        return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
    }
}
```

-

```
# Subcategory.php

class Subcategory extends Model
{  
    public function category()
    {    
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
$color = Request::first()->subcategory->category->color;
```

Of course, you can add a computed attribute to your `Request` class to easy access (keep in mind that this could increase the number of queries):

```
# Request.php

class Request extends Model
{  
    public function subcategory()
    {    
        return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
    }

    public function getColorAttribute()
    {    
        return $this->subcategory->category->color;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$color = Request::first()->color;
```